# UISearchDisplayController - Clicking overlay, method called?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Is there a delegate method that gets called when a user clicks on the dark overlay, which basically removes first responder status from the UISearchDisplayController? (I cannot find one in the docs.)

I would like to know when users click the black overlay, and the keyboard is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the UISearchDisplayDelegate then:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
```

should be called upon tapping the overlay.

I messed around with this components a few months back but ended up not using it because you can not change its standard behavior much.

What I did found out is that it is just a wrapper for the `UISearchBar`, so you can access the searchBar on your `SearchDisplayController` like this:

```
[searchDisplayController.searchBar setDelegate:self];
```

This way gives you a bit more freedom to access the delegate methods of the searchBar component itself. Like `textDidChange`, `cancelButtonClicked` etc.